# manipulation of strings in python

Tags: python

What is the easiest method to convert following string:

```
s = "my_data [0.046, 0.028, 0.01]"
```

into the string exactly as below:

```
my_data 0.046 0.028 0.01
```

Comment: That input is not valid Python code. Do you get it as a string?

Comment: @Nirock Then you haven't seen much :p

Comment: @nils So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems slightly more readable than the other solutions:

```
s = "my_data [0.046, 0.028, 0.01]"
for replacer in ('[', ']', ','):
    s = s.replace(replacer, '')
```

This can be compressed into a one-liner, but it doesn't seem as elegant/simple:

```
s = "my_data [0.046, 0.028, 0.01]".replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "my_data [0.046, 0.028, 0.01]"
" ".join(i.strip("[,]") for i in s.split(" "))
# output: 'my_data 0.046 0.028 0.01'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it as a new string, then why not:

```
import re
s = "my_data [0.046, 0.028, 0.01]"
print re.sub("[\[\],]", "", s)
```